# Rails : Drop down in simple_form doesn't retain value when directed to edit path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a drop down selector in a form and even after saving an object, when I go to my edit page, the drop down reverts to the first item. If submit is clicked, the value changes to the first item in the list.

In this case the drop down contains a list of states. Every time I go to the edit page, Alabama is selected and if I don't manually change the value back to what it initially was, the state becomes Alabama.

```
<%= simple_form_for @event, url: coin_event_path(@coin.id) do |f| %>    
<%= f.input :content, :label => "Event Description", class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.input :link, :label => "Link to Event", class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.input :date, order: [:month, :day, :year], class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.input :time, as: :time, html5: true, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.input :city, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.select :state, options_for_select(us_states),{}, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.input :description, :label => "Event Description", class: 'form-control' %>
<% if can? :destroy, Event %>
     <%= f.select :accepted, [['Accepted', true], ['Not Accepted', false]] %>
<% end %>
<%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>

<%= link_to "Back", coin_path(@coin.id), class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

How do I change this so it stays on the state that it's supposed to?

Comment: I believe the `{}` is overriding any value that is inferred. `f.input :state, :as => :select, :collection => us_states` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `selected`, like:

```
options_for_select(us_states, selected: "set_current_value")
```

More usage examples - [options_for_select()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) docs.